# Can I have MacOS mute system volume if a BT connection breaks for any reason?

Tags: macos, audio, bluetooth

The scenario: using bluetooth (Beatz) to listen to music and I may get up and walk away. If I get too far away and the connection breaks, it continues to play on my computer.

In the case of my computer being in a public space, I don't really want this to happen. At the moment I'm trying to remember to mute the system volume before walking away.

I'm imagining there is a *power user* solution to this, but also maybe something a bit more basic I wasn't even aware of.

Comment: I was pointed to https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/automute-preventing-awkward/id1118136179?mt=12 and it will possibly work, need to actually test it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid this using this method:

1. Without your Bluetooth headphones connected, **mute the output volume** in macOS
2. **Connect** your Bluetooth headphones. Make sure that they are the active output device.
3. **Set your preferred volume** for your headphones.
4. **Play music** (e.g. with iTunes) with your headphones still connected.

Test this method by simply **turning off** your headphones.

Comment: Yeah, good idea. I think the AutoMute software (my comment above) is _better_ if you're okay with using 3rd party tools. Mostly because it's a download, run, and _forget about it_ solution. But this is a nice answer to accept as a good "official one".

Answer (score 1):

An alternative answer I briefly mentioned in a comment is using a tool called AutoMute.

https://github.com/Lorenzo45/AutoMute

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/automute-preventing-awkward/id1118136179?mt=12

It works very well, I think.

I selected another answer as correct because it is a native solution. However, it requires a mental step whenever you want to go about doing it. Personally, I opted in for AutoMute.